# How old is an installed R package?

Tags: r

Is it possible to get the year that an installed R package is released using some R code? I can get the version, but then have to look it up on the internet, when this version was released.
Background: I am working for the Swiss Federal Statistical Office and a small group is trying to get a better R environment (we are working for example with the dplyr version 0.7.4 from 2017... and it is not possible to install a newer version...).

Cheers

Renger

Comment: Maybe with `citation("package")`?

Comment: I don't know of any existing ways to get the release date of a particular package version other than looking at the CRAN website. But maybe you can solve your problem a different way by using something like the [RStudio Package Manager](https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/-1/packages). With the package manager you can get a URL for a CRAN repo as of a particular date. So you can get all the package versions available on that date.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`versions`](https://github.com/goldingn/versions) package to get a timestamp of package version. The package pulls the published versions of the package from the [*MRAN snapshot server.*](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility)

```
versions::installed.versions("dplyr")
# [1] "1.0.7"
versions::available.versions("dplyr")
# $dplyr
# version       date available
# 1    1.0.7 2021-06-18      TRUE
# 2    1.0.6 2021-05-05      TRUE
# 3    1.0.5 2021-03-05      TRUE
# ...
```

## Package age

So if you want to answer the specific question about the package age you can do the following:

```
how_old <- function(pkg, lib = .libPaths()[1], return_age = FALSE) {
    pkg_ver <- versions::installed.versions(pkgs = pkg, lib = lib)
    av_vers <- versions::available.versions(pkgs = pkg)
    pkg_dte <- subset.data.frame(
        x = as.data.frame(unname(av_vers)),
        subset = version == pkg_ver,
        select = date,
        drop = TRUE
    )
    pkg_dte <- as.Date(pkg_dte)
    if (return_age) {
        return(epocakir::dob2age(dob = pkg_dte))
    } else {
        return(pkg_dte)
    }
}

how_old("dplyr", return_age = TRUE)
```

### Results

```
[1] "1123200s (~1.86 weeks)"
```

---

## Package creation

Or if you want to find out when package was installed locally.

```
when_created <- function(pkg, lib = .libPaths()[1]) {
    # Package will always have DESCRIPTION file so that's a safe bet
    desc_file <- system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = pkg, lib.loc = lib)
    info <- fs::file_info(desc_file)
    info$birth_time
}

when_created("dplyr")
```

### Results

```
# [1] "2021-06-25 08:47:21 BST"
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Jonathan recommended, if the package has a citation, then you can call the year in the citation.

```
citation("dplyr")$year
```

An alternative is to get the date from a list of available versions of a package.

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/cran/versions")
library(versions)

x <- versions::available.versions(c("dplyr", "ggplot2"))

version_year <-
  function(x,
           package.name = "",
           version = "") {
    pckg <- x[[package.name]]
    row <- which(pckg$version == version)
    return(pckg$date[row])
  }

version_year(x, "ggplot2", version = "2.0.0")
#[1] "2015-12-18"
```

Comment: Just added an alternative using `versions` to get a list of available package versions, which you can then get the date from.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you can find out when a package was created from its `DESCRIPTION`:

```
packageDescription(pkg)$Packaged
```

In fact, `citation` falls back to this very field if no other date was given (either as `Date/Publication` or via an explicit `CITATION` file).